Next.js App Behavior Differences on Netlify vs. Azure with getServerSideProps
I'm working on a Next.js application that's deployed on two environments: Netlify and an Azure server. I'm having an issue on the Netlify that doesn't occur on Azure.
I have a button that opens a component, when I click on the button on a page that uses getServerSideProps, I get a 404 error while trying to fetch data from a JSON file (game.json). The exact error message is:
GET https://net-develop.netlify.app/_next/data/Go_II7-X0zXHdlJp6S9Kd/en/game.json 404 (Not Found)
This error occurs only on the Netlify and not on the Azure server, where the application behaves as expected.
Why would getServerSideProps cause a 404 error when fetching data only on Netlify and not on Azure?
Is there a specific configuration for Next.js on Netlify that I might be missing which is causing this issue?
